# Error for arrays in hash keys

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to push 2 arrays in `VALUES`. One key, 2 values ---> 2 values are arrays in my case

```
my %hash

%hash{'one'} -->> is my key in hash

my @array1= ('apple', 'banana', 'orange');

my @array2 =('banana', 'orange','papaya','cherry');
```

I am stuck putting these array to my hashkey

```
push @{$hash{'one'}}, [ @array1 ]

push @{$hash{'one'}}, [ @array2 ]
```

When I try to run the program, I get an error:`can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "stricts refs"`

If I change my code to something like:

```
@{$hash{'one'}}= \@array1

@{$hash{'one'}}= \@array2
```

This also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion here (either by you, or by me, I can't quite tell which).

It all depends on what you want your final data structure to look like.  I believe what you're looking for is to have the value associated with key 'one' of %hash to be an array reference with two elements, each of which are themselves array references, like this:

```
# We'll call this "STRUCT-ONE"
%hash = (
   'one' => [
      ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
      ['banana', 'orange','papaya','cherry'],
   ],
);
```

...or, perhaps you instead intend for there to be only one array reference as the value, like so:

```
# Let's call this "STRUCT=TWO"
%hash = (
   'one' => [
      ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'banana', 'orange','papaya','cherry'],
   ],
);
```

The syntax to populate each of these structures would be different depending on which of the above you're looking for.

For each result, you would initialize your values the same way:

```
my %hash = ();
my @array1= ('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
my @array2 =('banana', 'orange','papaya','cherry');
```

...and, for "STRUCT-ONE", you would write something like:

```
$hash{'one'} = [];
push(@{$hash{'one'}}, [@array1]);
push(@{$hash{'one'}}, [@array2]);
```

...or, these last two lines could be combined like so:

```
push(@{$hash{'one'}}, [@array1], [@array2]);
```

Alternatively, for "STRUCT-TWO" above, you would change this to:

```
push(@{$hash{'one'}}, @array1, @array2);
```

(Note that I've simply removed the anonymous array reference syntax of '[]').

One final comment... you'll notice that I used '[@array1]' to create a new anonymous array reference (and populate it with the contents of the existing array (essentially performing a copy of the array contents)) instead of taking a reference to the existing array using a backslash '\@array1'.  Which option you choose depends on what you really intend. I chose the former so that you have an isolated data structure (and so further modification of either @array1 or @array2 will not impact your %hash contents.  If, however, you have a very large array and do not wish to copy it in memory (and you know the contents are really immutable), then taking a reference to the existing array may be a better choice.

In the end, I would suggest using [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) as a diagnostic tool to examine what your data structures actually look like (that, or a judicious use of the [Perl debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) (if you're familiar with how to use that)).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That thing really helped me a lot. 
I am using Dumper to check out my bugs. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
$hash{'one'} = ();
push $hash{'one'},@array1;
```

Comment: @DeathMetal You can keep on appending arrays to the hash value.

Comment: `$hash{'one'} = ()` is wrong. You cannot assign an empty list to a scalar value. You want `[]`.

Comment: @TLP it may look strange, but you can and result is `undef` in scalar context. `perl -Mstrict -we 'my $x = ();'`

Comment: @mpapec No, you can't assign an empty list to a scalar. It is a nonsense statement. It is like doing `my (@foo, $bar) = (1 .. 10);` -- the list is exhausted, so no value is left over for `$bar`. This only works by coincidence, because autovivification fixes it in the end. And it looks very misleading.

Comment: @TLP So does `@hash{'one'} = ()` makes sense?

Comment: @cppcoder Not really, no. For example, say you do this: `my @foo = qw(some values); $hash{one} = \@foo; ... $hash{one} = (); push @{$hash{one}}, "more values"; print @foo;` -- this wont work, because you destroyed the reference to `@foo` by assigning `undef` to the hash, but thinking you assigned an empty list.

Comment: @TLP it looks like new question candidate then. Personally I would make distinction between `you can't do it` and `it doesn't make sense` categories.

Comment: @mpapec Well... in Perl you "can do" many things, but as the saying goes, just because you can doesn't mean you should. In this case, it is misleading, which is why I am objecting to it: It doesn't do what it looks like it does.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @array1 = ('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
my @array2 =('banana', 'orange','papaya','cherry');

my %hash;
$hash{one} = [@array1];
push(@{ $hash{one} }, @array2);
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'one' => [
                     'apple',
                     'banana',
                     'orange',
                     'banana',
                     'orange',
                     'papaya',
                     'cherry'
                   ]
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

`$hash{'one'}` has already scalar value `1` and can't be used as array reference as your code suggest.

You can,

```
$hash{'one'} = [] if ref($hash{'one'}) ne "ARRAY";
push @{$hash{'one'}}, [ @array1 ];
```

Comment: ohh.. damn..</br>
can I not replace the values?

Comment: I can push the arrays with above help. Thanks much.
But while printing it, I can only see `array1's cherry` and `array2's orange`